# Delphi 2007 with Indy 9

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, indy-9

I see that Delphi 2007 comes with Indy 9 and Indy 10 integrated.
Both are included in the same search path.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\source\
```

I did not find a way to configure Delphi to take Indy 9. 
It always takes Indy 10.

Is there a way to configure Delphi, without deleting all Indy 10 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented on the [Indy forums](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewforum.php?f=7), you must uninstall the Indy 10 packages from the IDE,  delete the Indy package binaries and then compile and install the Indy 9 packages.

Comment: Worked. Additionally I had to set the paths for Indy 9